# RoR Bundler problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, bundler

I installed everything from the bottom up and thought it was working fine until I ran a `bundle install`

Has anyone ever seen this? Any ideas? Please help. Thanks.

```
bundle install
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/format.rb:38:in `from_file_by_path': Cannot load gem at [/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/cache/rake-0.8.7.gem] in /home/ec2-user/anotherApp (Gem::Exception)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/source.rb:73:in `fetch'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/installer.rb:45:in `block in run'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `block in each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/installer.rb:44:in `run'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/installer.rb:8:in `install'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/cli.rb:226:in `install'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:246:in `dispatch'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:389:in `start'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/bin/bundle:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/bundle:19:in `<main>'
```

Comment: did you try to update rubygems? (gem update --system)

Comment: @nash, I tried using `gem update --system` which then prompted me to do `gem install rubygems-update` and then `update_rubygems`. That worked and seems to be fine now! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you install Ruby 1.9.2-x from source it still installs the gems to /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/... which is a bit of a WTF ([relevant](http://www.rubyinside.com/ruby-1-9-2-released-3700.html)). I too got this error but it can also be caused by a permissions issue. So try running the command again as root (assuming you're running into this on a *nix system). Yes, that is not ideal however you may find it works and at least you can keep on going on the path to figuring things out (and it's all in a test VM anyway, right?).

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended to use Ruby 1.9.1 with Rails. Better 1.8.7 or 1.9.2, see http://rubyonrails.org/download. Looks like you use the Debian/Ubuntu Ruby. 1.8.7 is available and usable in Debian/Ubuntu, install the ruby-full meta package via apt. Or compile Ruby 1.9.2 directly or via the Ruby Version Manager (rvm). Do not install rubygems via apt.

Comment: would I need to rebuild rails as well? Or can I just build 1.9.2 from source?

Comment: If you use rvm, you need to install all gems again. rvm allows you to use several Ruby versions on the same system and is very popular in the Ruby community. If you compile it from the source, you might be able to use the installed gems, but maybe it's better to install the gems again...